# How can we create an Azure VM with trusted launch enabled with Azure SDK in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, virtual-machine

some methods does not exist as java example, some body to help me'

I tried to convert for example in java but I cant find some solution to create vm with c#code with trusted launched parameters, some body that knows the methods or solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we create an Azure VM with trusted launch enabled with Azure SDK in C#

You can use the below C# code to create an Azure virtual machine with **`trusted launch enabled`**.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using Azure;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models;


ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

string rgName = "your-resource-group-name";
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync(rgName);
VirtualMachineCollection vmCollection = resourceGroup.GetVirtualMachines();
string vmName = "your-virtual-machine-name";
VirtualMachineData input = new VirtualMachineData(resourceGroup.Data.Location)
{
    HardwareProfile = new VirtualMachineHardwareProfile()
    {
        VmSize = VirtualMachineSizeType.StandardB2S
    },
    OSProfile = new VirtualMachineOSProfile()
    {
        AdminUsername = "xxx",
        AdminPassword = "xxx",
        ComputerName = "your-vm-name"

    },
    NetworkProfile = new VirtualMachineNetworkProfile()
    {
        NetworkInterfaces =
        {
            new VirtualMachineNetworkInterfaceReference()
            {
                Id = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/xxxx"),
                Primary = true,
            }
        }
    },
    StorageProfile = new VirtualMachineStorageProfile()
    {
        OSDisk = new VirtualMachineOSDisk(DiskCreateOptionType.FromImage)
        {
            OSType = SupportedOperatingSystemType.Windows,
            Caching = CachingType.ReadWrite,
            ManagedDisk = new VirtualMachineManagedDisk()
            {
                StorageAccountType = StorageAccountType.StandardLrs
            }
        },
        ImageReference = new ImageReference()
        {
            Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            Offer = "WindowsServer",
            Sku = "2019-datacenter-gensecond",
            Version = "latest",
        }
    },
    SecurityProfile = new SecurityProfile()
    {
        SecurityType = "TrustedLaunch",
        UefiSettings = new UefiSettings()
        {
            IsSecureBootEnabled = true,
            IsVirtualTpmEnabled = true,
        },
        EncryptionAtHost= true
    }
};
ArmOperation<VirtualMachineResource> lro = await vmCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, vmName, input);
VirtualMachineResource vm = lro.Value
```

**Output:**

[image]

The above code executed and created an Azure virtual machine with trusted launch enabled.

**Reference:**

[Azure-sdk-for-net/sdk/compute/Azure.ResourceManager.Compute/Virtualmachines](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/compute/Azure.ResourceManager.Compute/samples/Sample2_ManagingVirtualMachines.md)