# Error at the moment to create azure vm wit trusted launch parameters

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

In this moment same issue happens to me:

RemoteException wrapping Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type.

c# code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJKRj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to create a VM using a gallery image that only supports the 'TrustedLaunch' security type. This error occurs when you try to create a VM with a different security type i.e., it will appear if you attempt to create a VM using a gallery image that has the security type Trusted Launch.

As per  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting-shared-images#creating-or-updating-a-vm-or-scale-sets-from-an-image-version) If a VM is created from a specialized image version, you will observe that the  `osProfile`  is not allowed due to admin username and password problem. Instead, you can create a VM with the security type as `Standard`, and then define and deploy the VM using a gallery image.

Here is a list from MS for [trusted_launch_VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch#virtual-machines-sizes)

From portal, if you are creating a VM with trusted launch security, below are the steps-

```
 AzurePortal->VirtualMachines->CreateVirtualMachine->Choose securityType->TrustedLaunchVirtualMachine
```

[image]

[image]

Reference Documents:

[Supported Gallery Images](https://the-tech-guy.in/2022/01/28/what-is-trusted-launch-for-azure-virtual-machines-and-why-should-you-use-it/)

[MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch-portal?tabs=portal,portal3,portal2)

[MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch-portal?tabs=portal,portal3,portal2)

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77332579/how-can-we-create-an-azure-vm-with-trusted-launch-enabled-with-azure-sdk-in-c)

To create a trusted launch VM using C# , you can use the below code-

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using Azure;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models;


ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

string rgName = "your-resource-group-name";
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync(rgName);
VirtualMachineCollection vmCollection = resourceGroup.GetVirtualMachines();
string vmName = "your-virtual-machine-name";
VirtualMachineData input = new VirtualMachineData(resourceGroup.Data.Location)
{
   HardwareProfile = new VirtualMachineHardwareProfile()
   {
       VmSize = VirtualMachineSizeType.StandardB2S
   },
   OSProfile = new VirtualMachineOSProfile()
   {
       AdminUsername = "xxx",
       AdminPassword = "xxx",
       ComputerName = "your-vm-name"

   },
   NetworkProfile = new VirtualMachineNetworkProfile()
   {
       NetworkInterfaces =
       {
           new VirtualMachineNetworkInterfaceReference()
           {
               Id = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/xxxx"),
               Primary = true,
           }
       }
   },
   StorageProfile = new VirtualMachineStorageProfile()
   {
       OSDisk = new VirtualMachineOSDisk(DiskCreateOptionType.FromImage)
       {
           OSType = SupportedOperatingSystemType.Windows,
           Caching = CachingType.ReadWrite,
           ManagedDisk = new VirtualMachineManagedDisk()
           {
               StorageAccountType = StorageAccountType.StandardLrs
           }
       },
       ImageReference = new ImageReference()
       {
           Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
           Offer = "WindowsServer",
           Sku = "2019-datacenter-gensecond",
           Version = "latest",
       }
   },
   SecurityProfile = new SecurityProfile()
   {
       SecurityType = "TrustedLaunch",
       UefiSettings = new UefiSettings()
       {
           IsSecureBootEnabled = true,
           IsVirtualTpmEnabled = true,
       },
       EncryptionAtHost= true
   }
};
ArmOperation<VirtualMachineResource> lro = await vmCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, vmName, input);
VirtualMachineResource vm = lro.Value
```

Output-
[image]

Reference Doc - [TrustedVMusingC#](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/compute/Azure.ResourceManager.Compute/samples/Sample2_ManagingVirtualMachines.md)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the main idea is do the same with commands and not using Graphic interface from Azure .

Comment: Updated the answer with the C# code and reference document.